# Count up different products

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
order_id  product_id
1         102
2         105
3         102
4         96
5         96
```

How would I get a count of the `product_id`s. The result I am looking to attain is:

```
product_id    count
96            2
102           2
105           1
```

The query I have tried is:

```
SELECT product_id, sum(product_id) from orders
```

But this of course produces an incorrect result with only one row. What would be the correct query here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) FROM orders GROUP BY product_id
```

Or if you want to name it...

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as product_count FROM orders GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT product_id, count(*) as count  from orders GROUP BY product_id
```